# Show that $\{f_k\}$ is an orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal

> Considering $f_k \in l^2  $ defined as
>
> $$\begin{align} f_{2n-1}&=\frac{e_{2n-1}-e_{2n}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
> f_{2n}&= \frac{e_{2n-1}+e_{2n}}{\sqrt{2}},
> \end{align}$$ where $e_k=(0,0,0,\dots, 0,1,0,\dots)$ with $1$ in $k$-th place.
>
> How to show that $\{f_k\}$ is an orthonormal set?

I tried to find the integral of inner product however ended up with something different.

Comment: What is the inner product on $\ell^2$? I don't think integrals have anything to do with it.

Comment: Should not we use the inner products in order to prove that it is orthonormal?  $<f,g>=\int(f^2)$ isn't like that?

Comment: We should use the *relevant* inner product for a given inner product space. On $\ell^2(\Bbb R)$ the relevant inner product is $\langle (a_n),(b_n) \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$.

Comment: @GregMartin So we end up with $\langle (f_{2n-1}),(f_{2n}) \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2 (e^2_{2n-1}-e^2_{2n})$ Sorry for stupid question, how to proceed with this?

Comment: Not quite—the $e_n$ are themselves infinite sequences. For example, \begin{align*}
f_1&=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}(1,-1,0,0,\dots)\\
f_2&=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}(1,1,0,0,\dots)\\
f_3&=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,1,-1,0,0,\dots)\\
f_4&=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,1,-1,0,0,\dots)\\
f_5&=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,\dots)\dots.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we show that $\left<e_n,e_m\right>=0$ for $n\neq m$.
We do this by considering 
$$\left<e_n,e_m\right> = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e_n^ke_m^k.$$
Remark that $e_n^k$ is only nonzero if $k=n$, and likewise $e_m^k$ is only nonzero if $k=m$. It follows that in every term, at least one of the factors is zero, since $n\neq m$. By consequence, the sum evaluates to zero.

The following proof for orthonormality illustrates how we apply this.

For $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2m}$ with $n < m$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\left<f_{2n},f_{2m}\right> = {} &\frac12\left<e_{2n-1} + e_{2n},e_{2m-1} + e_{2m}\right> \\
= {} & \frac12\left(\left<e_{2n-1},e_{2m-1}\right> + \left<e_{2n},e_{2m-1}\right> + \left<e_{2n-1},e_{2m}\right> + \left<e_{2n},e_{2m}\right>\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Because $n<m$, the operands are orthogonal in every scalar product, which means every scalar product is zero.
I will do the calculations for the third product, since it's slightly less trivial. Since $n<m$ we have $n\leq m-1$, which means $2n\leq 2m-2 < 2m-1$. Therefore, $e_{2n}$ is not equal (and hence is orthogonal) to $e_{2m-1}$. For the other cases, we make the same inequality argument, but finding the needed inequality is easier.

For $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2m-1}$ with $n < m$, we get the same four scalar products, but the last two will be prepended by a minus sign, which doesn't invalidate the above argument.

For $f_{2n-1}$ and $f_{2n}$ with $n < m$ we get

$$
\begin{align*}
\left<f_{2n-1},f_{2n}\right> = {} &\frac12\left<e_{2n-1} - e_{2n},e_{2n-1} + e_{2n}\right> \\
= {} & \frac12\left(\left<e_{2n-1},e_{2n-1}\right> - \left<e_{2n},e_{2n-1}\right> + \left<e_{2n-1},e_{2n}\right> - \left<e_{2n},e_{2n}\right>\right) \\
= {} & \frac12(1+0+0-1) = 0.
\end{align*}
$$

We have now proven that the $f_k$ are orthogonal. To complete the argument, we consider
$$
\begin{align*}
\left<f_{n},f_{n}\right> = {} &\frac12\left<e_{n-1} \pm e_{n},e_{n-1} \pm e_{n}\right> \\
= {} & \frac12\left(\left<e_{n-1},e_{n-1}\right> \pm \left<e_{n-1},e_{n}\right> \pm \left<e_{n},e_{n-1}\right> + \left<e_{n},e_{n}\right>\right) \\
= {} & \frac12(1 \pm 0 \pm 0 + 1) = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Sir, thanks for detailed and very clear answer, I have one more question which elements of $l^2$ are in $lin\{f_1,f_2,f_3,...f_{2N-1},f_{2N}\}$? Thanks

Comment: No problem! Those $f_i$ are independent and are contained in the subset $l\subset l^2$ for which the $i$th component of every element can only be nonzero when $i\leq 2N$. It follows that the $f_i$ span $l$, because the dimension of $l$ is $2N$.